# Disable "Quick edit" for list

Tags: 2013, list

How do I disable this function from XML? Anywhere in Content Type or List Definition or List Instance?

Answer (score 4):

If you want the quick solution to disable, you can hide that with the help of below CSS using a Content Editor Web Part in SharePoint 2013.

```
#Ribbon\.Library\.ViewFormat\.Datasheet-Large {
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293646/enabling-in-line-editing-for-a-view-in-list-definition)

You can try to use InlineEdit property of a list view

```
<View ...>
  <ViewFields ... />
  <Query ... />
  <Aggregations Value="Off" />
  <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
  <Mobile ... />
  <InlineEdit>TRUE</InlineEdit>
  <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
  <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
  <ParameterBindings>
    <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
  </ParameterBindings>
</View>
```

Answer (score 3):

<s>Defining the `InlineEdit` element radically changes the look of the list view.</s>

**Better approach:** You can disable quick edit mode in the `View` element of the List definition (Schema.xml) by adding the `TabularView` attribute and setting it's value to `FALSE`.

Unfortunately, this attribute is not described in the official documentation ([see `Attributes` section on MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms438338.aspx)), but it works. It hides the `Quick edit` button from the ribbon and also hides the `edit` link from the view.

Example:

```
<View ... TabularView="FALSE">
  ...
</View>
```

### UPDATE

You must also add the `MasterVersion="4"` attribute for `View` element. Without this attribute item selection checkboxes become broken. So the correct code is:

```
<View ... TabularView="FALSE" MasterVersion="4">
  ...
</View>
```

### UPDATE 2

All above text is incorrect. See [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/146693/54633).