# Change Quick edit on list on SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, powershell

I would like to set list Quick edit parameter programmatically or by schema.xml, but I can't find way to do it.

View has parameter InlineEdit, but SharePoint has to set it with another way.

How can I change this property by C#, powershell, xml in schema? Thanks

Update:

**SPList.DisableGridEditing** is the parameter.

In schema.xml:

```
<List ... DisableGridEditing="TRUE">
```

Comment: Update: Just found the answer. DisableGridEditing is the parameter I was looking for.

Comment: Please post that as an answer so you can correctly mark it as your preferred answer and put the question in a resolved state

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**SPList.DisableGridEditing** is the parameter.

In schema.xml:

```
<List ... DisableGridEditing="TRUE">
```

Comment: Thanks! I would be more than happy to meet the developer from Microsoft, that for this property that name with 'Disable' gave, although all of the simlar bool-type properties are called 'Enable*' :-)