# Disable quick edit for a particular list view in spd13

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, list-view, quick-edit

I have a list with 2 views : All items and Requetsers
I want to disable the quick edit link for requester view.

I have embedded these view on a webpart page as a webpart.

Comment: See [1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92750/disable-quick-edit-for-list/183528), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293646/enabling-in-line-editing-for-a-view-in-list-definition), [3](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146338/change-quick-edit-on-list-on-sharepoint-2013/146693#146693). It depends on your approach, but I believe one of these holds the answer for your case.

Comment: do you require add new item in toolbar? If not then you can use List View Web Part property pane, and set `Toolbar type` to `No Toolbar`.

Comment: You can add the css to that listview page.
for example you can add the script editor web part with css to requester.aspx page to hide the quick edit.

Comment: @moe Yes 3rd one seems helpful but where exactly do I find DisableGridEditing property?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the css to that listview page.
for example you can add the script editor web part with css to requester.aspx page to hide the quick edit.

Comment: Please Add more details like CSS Style , detail steps !

Comment: this is good for temporary cosmetic changes but I require a code based solution. This CSS worked for me - :                                          
 table#Hero-WPQ3 &gt; tbody &gt; tr &gt; td{ 
color:white;
}
table#Hero-WPQ3 &gt; tbody &gt; tr &gt; td &gt; a:last-child {
display:none;

Comment: @SanjanaChhabira: This css does not disable the Quick Edit button in the View Format group on the List ribbon does it?

Comment: @pholpar : It does. ID must be different for you. For me it was WPQ3. Check whats for yours? You can check with inspect element